# Install-Module fails for AWSPowerShell.NetCore

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to install AWSPowerShell.NetCore on my Windows 10 x64 system running PowerShell 5.1.17763.771:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> $PSversionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.771
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.771
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I've extracted the code to a module directory c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> dir .\AWSPowerShell.NetCore\


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AWSPowerShell.NetCore


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2/27/2020   3:55 PM                4.0.4.0
```

It shows up in $Env:PSModulePath.  When I try to install it I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> Install-Module -name AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Install-Module : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'name'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Module -name AWSPowerShell.NetCore
+                ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Module], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Install-Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an older version of PowerShell installed.  Older version of Install-Module does not support the parameter name 'Name'. Remove any old version and upgrade to the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below command to confirm the source module responsible for Install-Module. Here is expected output:

```
Get-Command Install-Module

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Install-Module                                     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet
```

If you'd like to check further, check the definition of the Install-Module function.

```
Get-Command Install-Module |Select-Object -expand Definition
help Install-Module -Parameter Name
```

This will show you if name parameter in fact does exist. 
Also, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget?view=powershell-7) link if there is any mismatch in your PowerShellget.

To verify package providers, run this command:

```
Get-PackageProvider
```